# Importing a .json Model into Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js

i'm new to Three.js and can't figure out how I can import a .json model downloaded from Clara.io

So for example, I downloaded this model: https://clara.io/view/eb3da9d9-152a-43e1-9a0d-3ac66bf76fc6
But I can't figure out how to actually embed it into a HTML file. :(

I tried something like:

```
loader = new (THREE.JSONLoader)

loader.load 'modules/squirtle-pokemon-go.json', (geometry, materials) ->
  material = new (THREE.MultiMaterial)(materials)
  object = new (THREE.Mesh)(geometry, material)
  scene.add object
  return
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: did you check same questions about importing json model.is there any specific problem for this model?

Comment: I did use the search function and tried pretty much all of the suggested answers, but i'm just getting a blank screen. :/

Comment: well i don't get blank screen.so problem is somewhere in your code.you should ost complete simple example code.also json file.jsfiddle example would we great

Answer (score 1):

You need to use THREE.ObjectLoader() to import your json model.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("modules/squirtle-pokemon-go.json", function ( obj ) {
     scene.add( obj );
});
```

Pls refer the link https://clara.io/learn/user-guide/data_exchange/threejs_export